# Server ftp inside Jboss 10

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ftp

I know the question does not make much sense, but I'd like to know if it's possible to embed an FTP (or SFTP/FTPS) server inside Jboss 10 application server.
Bear me for how much this question can seem stupid.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at [Apache FtpServer](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/index.html) specifically the [embedding guide](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/embedding_ftpserver.html).  You could start this up with a @Singleton or @Startup or inside of a servlet context listener.